Next.js API Route Works Locally but Fails in Production with Error 404
My Next.js app works well on localhost, but in production, it shows error in the console either:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () /api/invoice/abc:1 (using Axios) or
GET https://www.example.com/api/invoice/abc 404 (Not Found) (using fetch)

I've tried to fix it without success. My Next.js version is 14.0.3, and the app is deployed on Vercel.
Here's the API route code (app/api/invoice/[id]/route.ts):
import { retrieveInvoice } from "@/service/invoiceService";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const data = await retrieveInvoice(request.url.split("/").pop() || "");
  return new Response(JSON.stringify(data), {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  });
}

And here's the client-side code that calls the API:
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchInvoice = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await axios.get(`/api/invoice/${invoiceId}`);
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  fetchInvoice();
}, []);

I tested with the actual address:
await axios.get(`https://example.com/api/invoice/${invoiceId}`);

and it didn't work either: GET https://www.example.com/api/invoice/abc 404 (Not Found) error.
When I used the Vercel address:
await axios.get(`https://example.vercel.app/api/invoice/${invoiceId}`);

I encountered a CORS error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.vercel.app/api/invoice/abc' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET https://example.vercel.app/api/invoice/abc net::ERR_FAILED 308 (Permanent Redirect)


because I redirected all addresses to example.com.
I'd appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

I had the same issue at one point. I used fetch however:
All I changed was /api/route to https://yourproj.vercel.app/api/route, telling next to check for the specific url instead of a relative one
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchInvoice = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await axios.get(`https://<yourapp>.vercel.app/api/invoice/${invoiceId}`);
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  fetchInvoice();
}, []);


I tested with the actual address: https://example.com/api/invoice/${invoiceId}, and it didn't work: GET https://www.example.com/api/invoice/abc 404 (Not Found) error.
When I used the Vercel address: https://example.vercel.app/api/invoice/${invoiceId}, I encountered a CORS error because I redirect all addresses to example.com. I added these info to the post.

@Tui it would appear that the error is a CORS error. Cross Origin Resource Sharing. Because youre domain is not example.vercel.app. This basically means that it can only be accessed on the domain, not by other domains. IE, I couldn't access example.com's apis because i'm not example.com

Hey thank you for helping me! I removed the redirect from example.vercel.app to example.com as your suggestion but the error persists: GET https://example.vercel.app/api/invoice/abc 404 (Not Found).

Hey, I'm not sure you fully understood what I meant. CORS means that unless you are the domain you're accessing (ie, google.com) you can't access the apis on it (ie: google.com/api).
Essentially, if the url https://example.vercel.app/api/invoice/abc exists then you would not be able to access it as you are not example.vercel.app
I am assuming how ever your url for your vercel deployment is not example.vercel.app however, so what you should do in your GET request, replace the example with whateve your website url name is. If you could share a github repo that would be great

I made a mistake by having 2 api folders, /app/api and /api. Deleting /api resolved the issue. Thanks for helping me solve the problem @Nebulous.
